# TypeScript Promise Series Execution

Tags: typescript, promise

I've a list of doc objects and there is a need to make a API call for every doc id in the list and want to execute the API calls in a series fashion. Promise.all and Promise.allSelected executes them in a concurrent manner, in Typescript

```
[
  {
    "doc_id": 11
  },
  {
    "doc_id": 22
  },
  {
    "doc_id": 33
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over your array, here: `documents` of type `Array<{ doc_id: number }>`, to execute them in the given order:

```
for (const document of documents) {

  const response = await callApi(document['doc_id']);

  // do someting with response
  // or call just await callApi(document['doc_id']);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Promise.all and Promise.allSettled will wait for the promises asynchronously and simultaneously, but **most API calls start the moment the Promise is created**. Consequently, it wouldn't solve your problem to create all the promises at once and then simply `await` them one by one instead of using Promise.all: You need to defer their creation to happen one by one.

If you want to delay the API call for the second doc, you need to make sure you `await` the first response before creating the Promise for the second response. ([pzaenger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223789/1426891) does this well.) If you're using `then` and `catch` rather than `await`, you'll need to make sure that the second call to your API happens in the `then` handler of the first call, and the third in the second, and so forth.

There are also tools to handle the general ["throttling" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38385419/1426891), which can ensure that only *n* unsettled promises coexist at once; doing API calls in sequence is merely the case where *n = 1*. You might prefer to use a fairly general throttling library here, since you might find it valuable in the future to handle a small finite number at once (*n = 3*) or throttle by time (e.g. 1 request per second). This would be difficult to implement if you rewrite your code to run serially, but easy to modify with a library.